# Bernoulli Matrix with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I'm trying to generate a Bernoulli matrix, with values bounded between -1 and 1. I am using OpenCV's `cv::Mat` as the data structure to hold the values. Is there an easy way to generate such a matrix? As far as I know, OpenCV does not provide a way to do this so I'm happy to use another library if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate through the values and assign a random number one-by-one.

Here is how to do that:

```
boost::random::mt19937 rng;         // produces randomness out of thin air
                                // see pseudo-random number generators
boost::random::uniform_int_distribution<> uni01(0,1);

Mat bernoulli; bernoulli.create(rows, cols,CV_32FC1);
MatIterator_<float> it = bernoulli.begin<float>(), it_end = bernoulli.end<float>();
for(;it!=it_end;++it)
  (*it) = uni01(rng) ? 1.0 : -1.0;
```